# JPA @Transaction

Tags: java, jpa, transactions

It seems to me that the common way of starting / stopping a transaction with Spring JPA is to annotate a public function with @Transactional

What I am not able to figure out is if it is possible to annotate a class to make the scope a bit wider.

Lets say that you have a webservice that invokes 3 functions, for the two first you wish to manipulate the data and leave it in the memory attached to the session, but on the third call you wish to store the changed entities. What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are talking about is also called *conversation management*.

Keep in mind that a **transaction must be as short as possible**. Keeping a database transaction during multiple request-response loops is not an option (for technical reasons : a transaction is bind to a thread, and in general 2 requests are handled by 2 different threads).

But, JPA provides the [Extended Persistence Context](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContextType.html) to help you implementing *conversation management*.

An extended persistence context can be use outside transaction boundaries for read-only operations ; all non-read-only operations must be executed within a transaction.
Basically, an extended persistence context can *join a transaction*. That's how you can commit your extended persistence context at the end of the conversation.